# Progressbar while loading MainActivity

Tags: android, user-interface, progress-bar

I'm trying to show a progresbar while my MainActivity is loading,
tried this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ProgressBar spinner;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ...do stuff...
}
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    openBT();
    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ...do stuff...
}
```

}

Problem: MainActivity is for about 5 seconds blank, and then the MainActivity is loaded. But it's not displaying the progressbar. How do i get ths fixed? And what is my mistake? Thanks!

.xml looks like this:

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Whole OnCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    function1btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.function1btn);
    ...
    btDataList = new ArrayList<>();

    mWaveLoadingView = (WaveLoadingView) findViewById(R.id.waveLoadingView);
    mWaveLoadingView.setShapeType(WaveLoadingView.ShapeType.CIRCLE);
    mWaveLoadingView.setCenterTitleColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    mWaveLoadingView.setCenterTitleStrokeColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    mWaveLoadingView.setCenterTitleStrokeWidth(2);
    mWaveLoadingView.setProgressValue(100);
    mWaveLoadingView.setBorderWidth(10);
    mWaveLoadingView.setAmplitudeRatio(20);
    mWaveLoadingView.setWaveColor(Color.argb(255,50,205,50)); // green -> 100%
    mWaveLoadingView.setBorderColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    mWaveLoadingView.setCenterTitle("No BT-Device connected");
    mWaveLoadingView.setAnimDuration(3000);
    mWaveLoadingView.pauseAnimation();
    mWaveLoadingView.resumeAnimation();
    mWaveLoadingView.cancelAnimation();
    mWaveLoadingView.startAnimation();

    final SharedPreferences mPrefsMaxCap = getSharedPreferences("label", 0);
    String mString = mPrefsMaxCap.getString("MaxCap", "0");
    maxEnergy = Integer.parseInt(mString);

    if (maxEnergy != 0){
        maxEnergyView.setText(mString);
    }

    function1btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });

    function2btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });

    function3btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
}
```

openBT() method:

```
private void openBT(){
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    checkBTState();
    Log.d(TAG, "...onStart - try connect...");
    // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    // Two things are needed to make a connection:
    //   A MAC address, which we got above.
    //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
    //     UUID for SPP.

    try {
        btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onStart() and socket create failed: " + e1.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
    // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
    try {
        btSocket.connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "...Connection ok...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onStart() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

    try {
        outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onStart() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
}
```

Comment: If you facing a problem when you open the application then set this theme to your launcher activity. android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Comment: tried it at my AndroidManifest in <application>-Tag is this correct? 
Getting this error: Cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: see my answer sir

Comment: may be u r doing any long running operation in main thread that's why UI freezes and progress bar not shown on the screen

Comment: blank means what? is it showing white screen?

Comment: yes, its showing a white screen. I've made a new thread for the openBT() method. Now my delay is about one second. But the app is still displaying a white screen the first second.

Comment: can you post openBT() method?

Comment: of course, i will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

call `View.GONE` in your `onResume()` method like this..

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work. Still getting my blank application screen for few seconds and then the application is completely loaded. I've tried the application without setVisibility(View.GONE) and the Progressbar is starting after those few seconds. Not directly when the application opens.

Comment: Which events or methods are you calling in your `Mainactivity` ?

Comment: And second thing ....You should call `openBT();` method in your  `onResume()` method

Comment: The setOnClickListeners for 3 Buttons, I'm loading a string variable from SharedPreferences and I'm configuring a mWaveLoadingView. I'm adding my whole OnCreate to the Question.
Edit: Thanks, changed the openBT() method

Answer (score -1):

If you facing a problem when you open the application then set this theme to your launcher activity.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.F‌​ullscreen"
```

See the below snippet.

```
    <application 
      your application name,icon,label etc.>

      <activity
        android:name="Your main launcher activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: i have not voted, why Android Studio is telling me: Cannot resolve symbol?